# Why Julia returns "\uf8ff" when I use  (Apple logo) unicode?

Tags: unicode, fonts, character-encoding, julia, glyph

I thought Julia supports raw unicode input, such as:

```
julia> test = "π£¢∞§"
"π£¢∞§"

julia>  = 1 ;

julia> print( )
1
```

However, it seems julia does not support  (Apple logo).

```
julia>  = 123
ERROR: syntax: invalid character ""

julia> test = ""
"\uf8ff"
```

I wonder what's the underlying reason for that, and whether there is a way I can use  character in Julia?

Answer (score 4):

I believe [this](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/unicode_apple_logo.html) link more properly explains the case of the unicode character that you see as apple's logo.

> The problem is that the unicode value used is one of several that is set aside for private use. That means that each operating system, or application, or implementation is free to use those unicode characters for anything they want. It just so happens that Apple has chosen to use unicode character U+F8FF (decimal value 63743, or on the web as either  or ) as the Apple Logo. But some Windows fonts put in a Windows logo. And some other fonts put in a Klingon Mummification glyph. Or elven script. Or anything they want. And if it isn't defined in your local font, you'll just see a square.

My opinion is that Julia simply doesn't use this special value for anything. This also explains why your "π£¢∞§" characters work nicely - they are proper unicode characters, more largely supported by different platforms.

As a side note, i too see a simple square instead of the apple logo on this instance.

**Edit**

[Here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/unicode-input/) is a list of unicode characters supported by Julia.

Comment: Your link is to the subset of unicode characters supported that have a REPL completion (like `\alpha`) defined. In fact, Julia should support Unicode 9.0 fully.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Alex's answer...

Apple's logo () isn't an official Unicode symbol. I think there are very few commercial logos and symbols in the main Unicode tables.

However, Unicode provides some 'anything goes' areas (called PUAs - private use areas) that companies and individuals can fill with their own symbols, so that their users can access certain special glyphs. The main PUA is U+E000 to U+F8FF. Depending on which font you're using, you'll find all kinds of stuff assigned to these codes. On a Mac, I can usually get the Apple logo at "\uf8ff", with the right font selected, but not the Ubuntu symbol or the Windows logo, unless I choose another font. (There's also a fallback mechanism, whereby if you request a code point that the current font doesn't have, the OS will find a suitable substitute in another font and use that.)

[[image: display apple icon[1]]

In Julia, you can only use certain Unicode characters for variable names. Julia wouldn't allow anything from the private use area anyway, unless some fonts were distributed to every computer and everyone agreed on who had which Unicode point. (Mathematica makes extensive use of PUA symbols in their notebooks, because they can and do install their own fonts, and can then access various glyphs from the PUA in the notebook with guaranteed results.)

You are allowed to use emoji characters as variable names, so you could try the Emoji apple, rather than the Apple apple:

[image]